# SASS each function not working

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass

I am trying to this but I am getting error on compile I don't know why and I am new to sass.

> Error: Invalid CSS after "    width: #{$i}%": expected expression
>   (e.g. 1px, bold), was ";"

```
$list:  5 10 13 15 18 20 25 30 40 50 60 65 70 75 78 80 90 97 100;
@each $i in $list {
  .width#{$i} {
    width: #{$i}%;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [`percentage`](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/Sass/Script/Functions.html#percentage-instance_method) function

```
width: percentage($i/100);
```

Comment: I tried this error is coming ($number: "5/100" is not a unitless number for `percentage')

Comment: @SureshPattu my code is updated